# sql query search for a value in an xml column

Tags: xml, t-sql, xpath, sql-server-2012, xquery

```
<MultiItems>
    <Items>
        <Profile>221</Profile>
        <Creator Company Name>pepsi</Creator Company Name>
        <Creator Contact Name>pepsico</Creator Contact Name>
        <SUPC>11</SUPC>
        <Keywords>beverages</Keywords>
    </Items>
</MultiItems>
```

This is how the xml looks like in a file
I have an xml column in my sql server database. It contains metadata information about a product. The different tags are different metadata for the product. How should I retrieve all the values from this xml including the creator contact name,supc and also how do I return the name of a tag that has no value in it.

Comment: @shnugo Thanks. the correct xml is <MultiItems><Item><Profile>211</Profile><Metadatas><Metadata><Control>1ccf8d18-3dd7-4a7e-a6ce-630bfd8f3358</Control><ControlTypeID>5ae9a004-c0de-4692-a9bd-e8f73926f4f3</ControlTypeID><Name>Creator Company Name:</Name><Value>SGS Test</Value><ControlDatas /></Metadata></Metadatas></Item></MultiItems>

Comment: I am looking for tags with no values in it. in this example name(is a field name but it has no value in its tag) has a field but no value in it.  <MultiItems><Item><Profile>234</Profile><Metadatas><Metadata><Control>53c72c46-575b-426a-903d-2969bda4efcd</Control><Name>Multi Lingual</Name><Value /><ControlDatas /></Metadata></Metadatas></Item><MultiItems>

Comment: 1) Place comments to the related answers or 2) place additional information into your question (use the edit option). 3) The XML from your comments includes some invisible characters which I had to remove, before I could test this... 4) The `<Name>` is not *with no values*? Look at my examples. But e.g. `<Value>` in the second example is empty. See my new answer.

Comment: @shnugo thanks i will try this . the <name> is the field name and the <value> is the value associated with field name. think of it as 2 columns of a table. So if I have 2 columns called field name and values. I will have multilingual in the 1st column but empty data in the 2nd column. I am looking for such tags

Answer (score 0):

Some things in advance:

- The XML posted in your question is invalid. I've told you so and you posted some examples in comments below your question.
- I'm using these examples now, although there are some weird characters within your posted XMLs, which I had to remove. You find them, when you step through the text with the cursor and you reach a position, where the cursor will not move...
- Your final example has not the correct closing tag.

Anyway, I do not really know, what you want. According to your question you are trying to read values, but in the comments you state, that you are looking for nodes without a value. However - I'll show both:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourXmlColumn XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
(N'<MultiItems>
  <Item>
    <Profile>211</Profile>
    <Metadatas>
      <Metadata>
        <Control>1ccf8d18-3‌​dd7-4a7e-a6ce-630bfd‌​8f3358</Control>
        <ControlTypeID>5ae9a004-‌​c0de-4692-a9bd-e8f73‌​926f4f3</ControlTypeID>
        <Name>Creator Company Name:</Name>
        <Value>SGS Test</Value>
        <ControlDatas />
      </Metadata>
    </Metadatas>
  </Item>
</MultiItems>')
,(N'<MultiItems>
  <Item>
    <Profile>234</Profile>
    <Metadatas>
      <Metadata>
        <Control>53c72c46-5‌​75b-426a-903d-2969bd‌​a4efcd</Control>
        <Name>Multi Lingual</Name>
        <Value />
        <ControlDatas />
      </Metadata>
    </Metadatas>
  </Item>
</MultiItems>');
```

--The query for values

```
SELECT t.id
      ,t.YourXmlColumn.value(N'(/MultiItems/Item/Profile/text())[1]',N'int') AS [Profile]
      ,t.YourXmlColumn.value(N'(/MultiItems/Item/Metadatas/Metadata/Control/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS [Control]
      ,t.YourXmlColumn.value(N'(/MultiItems/Item/Metadatas/Metadata/Name/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS [Name]
      ,t.YourXmlColumn.value(N'(/MultiItems/Item/Metadatas/Metadata/Value/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS [Value]
FROM @tbl AS t;
```

--If you want to see all nodes with no text within `<Metadata>` try this

```
SELECT t.id
      ,nd.value(N'local-name(.)',N'nvarchar(max)') AS EmptyNodeName
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY t.YourXmlColumn.nodes(N'//Metadata/*[empty(text())]') AS A(nd)
```

### UPDATE

My *wrong* answer is a result of your *wrong wording*

> want to return the name of the tag that has no value

The **tag that has no value** is the one with no value, not the other one...

Try this

```
SELECT t.id
      ,nd.value(N'text()[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS EmptyNodeName
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY t.YourXmlColumn.nodes(N'//Metadata[empty(Value/text())]/Name') AS A(nd);
```

This will find a `<Name>` node below `<Metadata>` in cases where the `Value/text()` is empty.

Comment: thanks for the query . In the second answer you  gave where it retrieves values of nodes with no value, I want to return the name of the tag that has no value. In the above example, <Name>Multi Lingual</Name> has no corresponding value in its </value> tag, so I want <name > tag or (MultiLingual) to be returned as a answer

Comment: Thanks a lot! this information saved me! Sorry for the errors I made.This was my first time asking a question.